# Do I need any special configuration for RESTfull client under WAS8.5.5

Tags: web-services, restful-authentication, restful-architecture, websphere-8

I have a very basic RESTfull service. It runs under WAS8.5.5 without any explicit security restrictions.

A RESTfull client runs under another WAS8.5.5. I use Apache Winks from WAS.

Should I configure the client application somehow to use the RESTfull service (add any items in web.xml, ibm-web-bnd.xml, create webservices.xml, etc.)?

I'm asking as the client receives 401 (Unauthorized) code. 
I receive expected results if I use the same URL from the browser. 
The client and the browser run under the same credentials.

Answer (score 0):

No special configuration for RESTfull is needed.  But you MUST add all security headers to a http request by hands to propagate the security context.

Answer (score 0):

it sounds like you have basic authentication configured for your endpoint. When you access the endpoint from your browser, you likely are asked for the user/pass in a pop-up window.

So from your client, you have to pass in the "Authorization" header, with a key that is "Basic xyz", where xyz is the base64 encoded version of user:pass

For more info, here's the spec link: https://www.w3.org/Protocols/HTTP/1.0/spec.html#Authorization